# Logic Behind MQx Sensors Calculation - Raspberry Pi

Tags: sensor, adc, raspberry-pi, voltage-divider, python

Would you please explain the logic behind this snippet of code which is taken from [here](https://github.com/tutRPi/Raspberry-Pi-Gas-Sensor-MQ/blob/master/mq.py) for calibrating MQx Sensor(s):

```
def MQResistanceCalculation(self, raw_adc):
      return float(self.RL_VALUE*(1023.0-raw_adc)/float(raw_adc));
```

in which `raw_adc` is the `MCP3008` reading, and `RL_VALUE` is the *load resistance* on the board, in kilo ohms and equals 5.

The thing is, *as far as I understand it*, the ADC works according to this equation:

```
Resolution of ADC / System Voltage = ADC Reading / Analog Voltage Measured
```

but I cannot see it implemented in the above-code (because I was following [this](https://www.jayconsystems.com/tutorials/gas-sensor-tutorial/) tutorial but for Arduino).

Furthermore, to get the value of `RS` in a gas according to the second above-mentioned tutorial, we follow this equation:

```
RS = [(VC x RL) / VRL] - RL
```

which also not seen in the entire code of the project that the first snippet of code comes from.

The Schema of this design is:

```
MQx Sensor -> Logic Level Converter -> MCP3008 -> RPi
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, or maybe I'm mixing up things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full answer:

Starting from **Ohm's Law**: `V = R * I` in which *V: Voltage, R: Resistance and I: Current*.

and in the simplest circuit of a **Voltage Divider** like this:

[image: voltage divider]

to measure any voltage we need two points, so V<sub>out</sub> can be measured in one of two ways:
(V<sub>in</sub> - V<sub>out</sub>) = R<sub>1</sub> * I<sub>1</sub> : in which V<sub>in</sub> here is the *positive* side of the electricity source.

**OR** 
(V<sub>out</sub> - V<sub>in</sub>) = R<sub>2</sub> * I<sub>2</sub> : in which V<sub>in</sub> here is the *negative* side and equals **0**.

We choose the easier choice where V<sub>in</sub> = 0, so V<sub>out</sub> = R<sub>2</sub> * I<sub>2</sub>.

Now, because there is no consumption of the current, we can assume I<sub>total</sub> = I<sub>1</sub> = I<sub>2</sub>.
So re-writing the above equation: V<sub>out</sub> = R<sub>2</sub> * I<sub>total</sub>.

Now because R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> connected in series, the law says R<sub>total</sub> = R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>2</sub>.

Back to Ohm's Law we can say: V<sub>in</sub> = R<sub>total</sub> * I<sub>total</sub>  -->  I<sub>total</sub> = V<sub>in</sub> / R<sub>total</sub>.

Using the last equation, we will have: V<sub>out</sub> = R<sub>2</sub> * (V<sub>in</sub> / R<sub>total</sub>), re-writing it again: V<sub>out</sub> = R<sub>2</sub> * (V<sub>in</sub> / R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>2</sub>).

Now the job is to find R<sub>1</sub>:

V<sub>out</sub> / R<sub>2</sub> = V<sub>in</sub> / (R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>2</sub>) -> (R<sub>2</sub> * V<sub>in</sub>)/V<sub>out</sub> = R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>2</sub>.

**Finally:**

R<sub>1</sub> = [(R<sub>2</sub> * V<sub>in</sub>)/V<sub>out</sub>] - R<sub>2</sub>. Which we also can re-write it in this way: R<sub>1</sub> = [(V<sub>in</sub>/V<sub>out</sub>)-1] * R<sub>2</sub>.

---

**Analog to Digital Converter (ADC):**

which receives a voltage value and convert it to an approximate corresponding digital value.

**Overview about ADC Resolution:**

Resolution determines the scale/level of the conversion, so for example, if we have a 2-bit ADC which can read up to 10V as input, the possible corresponding values will be:

```
Voltage     2-Bit Digital Rep.

0 to 2.5        00
2.5 to 5        01
5 to 7.5        10
7.5 to 10       11
```

So, it's 2<sup>2</sup> = 4 different numbers. So the range of Digital Values is: 0 to 3, The same way, if we have 10-bit ADC ->  2<sup>10</sup> = 1024, the range of Digital Values is: 0 to 1023.

**Relating ADC Value to Voltage:**

The ADC reports a ratiometric value. This means that for 10-bit ADC assumes 5V (System Voltage) is 1023 and anything less than 5V will be a ratio between 5V and 1023.

We use this simple equation:

```
ADC Resolution / System Voltage = ADC Reading / Analog Voltage Measured
```

Now, re-writing it:

```
 System Voltage = (Analog Voltage Measured * ADC Resolution) / ADC Reading
```

in which System Voltage and Analog Voltage Measured correspond to the V<sub>in</sub> and V<sub>out</sub> in the Voltage Divider Equation respectively.

Using this in the Voltage Divider Equation gives us:

R<sub>1</sub> = [((Analog Voltage Measured * ADC Resolution) / ADC Reading) / Analog Voltage Measured - 1] * R<sub>2</sub>

Keep re-writing it:

R<sub>1</sub> = [(Analog Voltage Measured * ADC Resolution) / (ADC Reading * Analog Voltage Measured) - 1] * R<sub>2</sub> ->

R<sub>1</sub> = [(ADC Resolution) / (ADC Reading) - 1] * R<sub>2</sub> ->

R<sub>1</sub> = [(ADC Resolution) /ADC Reading) - (ADC Reading/ADC Reading)] * R<sub>2</sub> ->

R<sub>1</sub> = [(ADC Resolution - ADC Reading)/ADC Reading)] * R<sub>2</sub> ->

**Finally:**

**R<sub>1</sub> = R<sub>2</sub> * (ADC Resolution - ADC Reading)/ADC Reading)** : in which R<sub>1</sub> is Sensor Resistance (R<sub>s</sub>), R<sub>2</sub> is Load Resistance (R<sub>L</sub>) and ADC Resolution is 1023.